# How to create a Page/Screen Object Model in Jetpack Compose Testing

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-testing

For basic testing, if I create a test class like below, it works fine.

```
class MyComposeTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun myTest() {

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Login").performClick()

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Home").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```

But what if i want to abstract some of these into separate classes for an end-to-end test?

e.g. I want to create a login page class with all locators for Login and similarly for Home page and simplify my test as

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
   val login = LoginPage() 
   val home = HomePage()

   login.loginBtn.performClick() 
   home.homeTxt.assertIsDisplayed()
}
```

I am not sure how my page classes (with locators) should look like to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the composeTestRule in the page's constructor. The code would look like this:

```kotlin
class BaseTestSuite {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()
}
```

```kotlin
class LoginPage(composeTestRule: ComposeContentTestRule) {
    val loginBtn = onNodeWithText("Login")

    fun tapLoginButton() {
        loginBtn.performClick() 
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MyTestSuite() : BaseTestSuite {
    val loginPage = LoginPage(composeTestRule) 

    @Test
    fun myTest() {
        loginPage.tapLoginButton()
    
        // rest of the code
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, let's see at how Kakao Compose DSL looks like:

```kotlin
// Screen class
class ComposeMainScreen(semanticsProvider: SemanticsNodeInteractionsProvider) :
      ComposeScreen<ComposeMainScreen>(
          semanticsProvider = semanticsProvider,
          // Screen in Kakao Compose can be a Node too due to 'viewBuilderAction' param.
          // 'viewBuilderAction' param is nullable.
          viewBuilderAction = { hasTestTag("ComposeMainScreen") }
 ) {
    
    // You can set clear parent-child relationship due to 'child' extension
     // Here, 'simpleFlakyButton' is a child of 'ComposeMainScreen' (that is Node too)
     val simpleFlakyButton: KNode = child {
         hasTestTag("main_screen_simple_flaky_button")
     }
}
    
// This annotation is here to make the test is appropriate for JVM environment (with Robolectric)
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
    // Test class declaration
class ComposeSimpleFlakyTest : TestCase(
      kaspressoBuilder = Kaspresso.Builder.withComposeSupport()
) {
    
      // Special rule for Compose tests
      @get:Rule
      val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<JetpackComposeActivity>()
    
        // Test DSL. It's so similar to Kakao or Kautomator DSL
      @Test
      fun test() = run {
          step("Open Flaky screen") {
              onComposeScreen<ComposeMainScreen>(composeTestRule) {
                  simpleFlakyButton {
                      assertIsDisplayed()
                      performClick()
                  }
              }
          }
    
          step("Click on the First button") {
              onComposeScreen<ComposeSimpleFlakyScreen>(composeTestRule) {
                  firstButton {
                        assertIsDisplayed()
                      performClick()
                  }
              }
          }
    
            // ...
      }
}
```

It works in the same way as the Page Object pattern using Espresso. Learn [more](https://kasperskylab.github.io/Kaspresso/Wiki/Jetpack_Compose/#kakao-compose-library)